# Fourier transform of a test function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

can someone help me to prove that :

the Fourier transform of a test function is not a test function ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Maybe you might want to let one of us know what exactly is a test function.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\varphi \in \mathcal D$, where $\mathcal D$ is the space of $\varphi \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb R)$ with the usual test function continuity notion.
Consider
$$
\tilde \varphi(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{dx}{(2\pi)^{1/2}}e^{-i\xi  x}\varphi(x)=\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{dx}{(2\pi)^{1/2}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-i\xi x)^n}{n!}\varphi(x);
$$
since the integral extends in fact only on the compact support of $\varphi$, it is easy to prove that the sum can be pulled out of the integral sign, yielding a series expansion for $\tilde \varphi (\xi)$
$$
\tilde \varphi (\xi) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{\mathbb R}\frac{dx}{(2\pi)^{1/2}}\frac{(-ix)^n}{n!}\varphi(x)\ \xi^n.
$$
This shows that $\tilde \varphi$ is analytic. Can you go on from here? Notice that $\tilde \varphi$ can be extended to be a holomorphic $\tilde \varphi (\xi + i \eta)$ and recall that holomorphic functions either have isolated zeroes or are identically vanishing.
Can you see why this collides with the definition of $\mathcal D$?

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I don't really see why this collides with the definition of D because according to me the zero function works

Comment: @ Rom Rom Start from a nonzero $\varphi(x)\in D$ and assume that its Fourier transform $\tilde \varphi$ is still in $D$; you can also express $\varphi$ as the reverse Fourier transform of $\tilde \varphi$: if $\tilde \varphi$ vanished identically, which is the only way to satisfy the holomorphism and compact support requirements, then $\varphi$ would vanish identically in the first place, which is absurd.